Can I remove this wedge out of my window?
I moved into my brand new home 2 years ago and I just noticed this on my window. Does anyone know what it's used for, and can I remove it as I notice it's causing a draft to come into my home?


It seems odd to be there.  Most people like to see straight lines, so something making a bend makes the window look odd/not done right.  Talk to the builder, maybe they forgot to take it out.  Homes usually have a few years to check for builder oops/mistakes.

Got a photo that's not from across the yard? Open the window and give us a proper look at it. Some windows have alignment pads. Or it's packaging that wasn't removed. Can't tell from way back here.

Do you have similar windows? Do they have that block?
